# How to hover over the angular autocomplete options

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I am running angular app, I have autocomplete when I hover over the autocomplete mat-options, I want to see entire customer number and name. I tried to do this

```
 <mat-form-field [style.cursor]="pointer" [style.cursor]="pointer" [style.width.px]=300  >
     <input class="selectCustomer" class="selectCustomerData" id="inputCustomer" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto"  [formControl]="customerFilterControl" [(ngModel)]="customerName">
     <mat-icon matSuffix>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
       <p id="spandiv">{{customerName}}</p>  
     <mat-autocomplete dropdown-arrow="true" panelWidth ="450px" #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith] = "displayFn">
        <mat-option class="CustomerDropDown" *ngFor="let customer of filteredOptions | async"   [value] ="customer.AccountID +' '+'('+ customer.AccountName + ')'" (onSelectionChange)="onCustomerChange(customer)">
         {{customer.AccountID}} ({{customer.AccountName}})  <p id="spandiv1">{{customer.AccountID}} ({{customer.AccountName}})</p> 
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```

[image]

Basically I want to see value when I hover on the mat-option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to do this is to put the option text inside a `div` element with a small `max-width`. Then style that `div` element so overflows are normally hidden, but not when the option text is being hovered.

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vzfpjy

One problem with this solution is that the user has to hover over the **text** of the option to show the full value.